# Error while Installing TensorFlow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

**Description:**
I am facing an issue while trying to install the TensorFlow Object Detection API. The installation process runs into an error related to the directory path "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/object_detection/tpu_exporters/testdata". I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to resolve it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Error Message:**
The error message I encounter during the installation process is:

```
Error: build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/object_detection/tpu_exporters/testdata
```

**Steps Taken:**
I followed the installation guide for the TensorFlow Object Detection API, which involves using

```
%%bash
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling TensorFlow and other related packages, but the error persists.

**System Information:**

- Python Version: 3.9.17
- TensorFlow Version: 2.13.0